# Best way to fetch core data update in the background

Tags: core-data, ios8, icloud

I am curious to the best way to fetch core data changes in the background, while my app is not active.

Just to clarify my users tend to use my app on one device (i.e. iPhone) and cause quite a few changes. then they go to another device and expect all the changed records to pop up immediately.

Currently my app takes about 20 seconds for all core data updates to propagate from iCloud once it has been opened and it listens for the appropriate notifications. Is there a good way to update this in the background so that the user does not have to wait?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible. Your app can only update its Core Data store via iCloud once it is active. To my knowledge, there is no available mechanism to make it active without user interaction - and to keep it active always does not seem to be feasible either.